# G++ Compilers for MonoDevelop

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, monodevelop

How do you setup a G++ compiler for MonoDevelop?

On both OS X and Windows Vista the default install complains about  "Compiler Not Found: g++".

Is MonoDevelop not a good cross platform IDE for C++ development (since it is a C#/Java IDE).

Thanks SO!

Comment: On MacOS, do you have G++ installed?

Comment: What should I install for G++ and GDB for mac?

Comment: Get the XCode installer.  Look at http://developer.apple.com/xcode/.

Comment: `Is MonoDevelop not a good cross platform IDE for C++ development (since it is a C#/Java IDE).`
It is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is not. 
C# and C++ are 2 different worlds. 
My suggestion: If you want to write xplatform apps in C++, get familiar with either wxWidgets or QT. 
wxWidgets has a more liberal license though and does not need a metacompiler. In the newest release it makes also use of the STL, if the compiler supports it.